# Is $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1$ a function?

Tags: functions

Today's I've heard in a lecture that:

$$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1$$

*is not a function*, as functions domain elements have a single corresponding image in the codomain.

Could someone clarify this. What type of things $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are called then?

Comment: I believe that you've misunderstood what the lecturer said or that he expressed himself poorly. I'd suggest that you ask him if that's what he really meant. What's true is that fx $x^2+y^2-1=0$ does not constitute a function from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: People hear a lot of things sometimes somewhere. Why you didn't check your textbooks or notes? Or even asked the person who said this what this means?

Comment: @Karl I asked him, he told me that $f$ is a curve. I'm pretty sure that he clearly stated that "$f$ is not a function". I just didn't want to make an argument.

Comment: Sorry, but in maths you have to be precise. As in the answers is said, it seems that you are confusing the function $f$ with a curve defined by $x_1^2+x_2^2-1$. These are different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must have mis-heard (or your lecturer mis-spoke). What is true is that the level set (at level $0$) of 
$$
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1
$$
i.e., the set defined by $\{ (x, y) \mid f(x, y) = 0\}$, is a circle, and that the circle is not the graph of any function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, because for a given $x$-value (e.g., $x = 0$) there are often two $y$-values (in this example, $y = \pm 1$) with the property that $(x,  y_1)$ and $(x, y_2)$ are both in the level set.

On the other hand, the implicit function theorem says that locally, under not-too-stringent conditions, a piece of the level set *will* be the graph of a function; you should perhaps read up on the implicit function theorem to see what this means more precisely.

Why do I think this is what's said? Because that's a really standard example in this topic. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's a perfectly fine function. If you want to be pedantic, the function is really
$$
f : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}
$$
where $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2+x_2^2-1$.

(One could argue that what you have written is the *value* of a function at a particular point.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ be sets and let $f$ be an object. Then $f$ is called a function if and only if $f$ assigns to every $x \in X$ some unique $y \in Y$.

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, we have $x^{2}+y^{2}-1 \in \mathbb{R}$ by definition. Since certainly $x^{2}+y^{2}-1$ denotes exactly one number, by definition the object assigning to every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ some unique number in $\mathbb{R}$, namely $x^{2}+y^{2}-1$, is a function.